# getLayoutParams returning null?

Tags: android

I've created a class that extends a View:

```
public class BoardView extends View  {
```

and I've specified the width and height of the BoardView in the application's main.xml file:

```
  <mypackage.BoardView
        android:id="@+id/board"         
        android:layout_width="270px" 
        android:layout_height="270px" />
```

I'm trying to get the width and height from a function that is called from the BoardView's constructor. Here's what I'm doing:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = this.getLayoutParams();
int h = p.height;
```

but getLayoutParams is always returning null.  Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure that layout parameters(i.e. instance of LayoutParams) will be available inside constructor of the View. I think, it will only be available after "layout" passes have been made. Read about [How Android draws views here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) Also, [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9cd129eb10673e2c/ba8170c29dd5c76c?lnk=gst&q=getHeight%28%29#ba8170c29dd5c76c) tries to pin point when exactly should you expect to get Measured dimensions of a View.

Note that if you are interested in just getting the attribute values passed via layout XML, you can use [AttributeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) instance passed as an argument to your constructor.

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
// attrs.getAttributeCount();
// attrs.getAttributeXXXvalue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

All I really needed was the XML attribute value which I could obtain from the AttributeSet in the constructor. Here's my (ugly) solution:

String ns = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
String v = attrs.getAttributeValue(ns, "layout_height");

// Convert "270px" to "270"
v = v.replace("px", "");

// At runtime this value is "270.0"
v = v.replace(".0", "");   

int h = Integer.parseInt(v);

Answer (score 18):

After the view is added to its parent the layout parameters are available. Try moving your code from the view constructor to `onAttachedToWindow()` because `getLayoutParams()` won't return `null` there.

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    assert getLayoutParams() != null;
}
```